# Using images from library with TLFTextField

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6, tlf

I can use inline images with TLFTextField referring to an URL. But I need to fetch it from library because it causing blinks every time when same image loaded. I tried to convert an image to MovieClip and load it like I could do it with TextField but no luck.

To be more specific I'm writing a chat application with icons but I couldn't find a decent solution about smilies.

Comment: See this thread if it helps: https://forums.adobe.com/message/3680874

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using *html* inside your TLF, you could then utilise library item identifiers as the *src* or the *img* tags.

```
<img src="myLibraryImage" width="100" height ="50"/>
```

**update:**
the below link documents someone experimenting with this a few years back where they:

- create TLF
- add a new TextFlow element
- add a new paragraph element
- add an InlineGraphicElement with the source as a class instantiation

[previous thread](https://taskinoor.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/as3-inline-graphics-using-text-layout-framework)

the InlineGraphicElement is documented here:
[InlineGraphicElement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/elements/InlineGraphicElement.html)

Comment: It does not work. TLF only loads images from URL, unlike TextField. I can load images from library with TextField but it has problems with floats.

Comment: hi Eren, I've updated the answer with an older thread on this subject which might help

Comment: I was able to fix the problem with inlineGraphicResolverFunction callback. I think the solution you referred also addresses a similar way of fixing the problem.

Comment: that's great, glad you sorted it.